# matching two data frame columns to a vector of length two to grab a value in the matching row in r

Tags: r

This is my first question on stackoverflow, 
here it goes.

I have a data frame that looks like-

```
data.frame1<- data.frame("ID" = c(1,2,3,4,5), "Col1" = c(1,4,12,15,6), "Col2"= c(3,6,2,4,1))
```

then I have two values

```
Value1 <- 4
Value2 <- 6
```

I want to check (value1,value2) for every pair in (col1,col2) to see if there is a match.

If there is a match I want to return the ID number, so in the example- it would return 2, and if there isn't a match I want it to return NA.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `df[df$Col1 == Value1 & df$Col2 == Value2,"ID"]` , df is your data frame name

Comment: please include example output.

Comment: You just need to specify the condition properly. `data.frame1$Col1==Value1 & data.frame1$Col2==Value2` will give you a boolean vector. `which(data.frame1$Col1==Value1 & data.frame1$Col2==Value2)` will give you the indices where the vector is `TRUE`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `which`:

```
with(data.frame1, ifelse(idx <- Col1 == Value1 & Col2 == Value2, which(idx), NA))
# [1] NA  2 NA NA NA
```

Or if you only want to return the matching indices:

```
with(data.frame1, which(Col1 == Value1 & Col2 == Value2))
# [1] 2
```

Comment: Thanks! this is exactly the type of method I was looking for.

Comment: You're welcome @AustinGoodrich. If this answers your question, please consider closing the question by setting the check mark next to the answer.